# Why does the Android app Keyguard not contain any components?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest, android-source

Below is the shortened content of AndroidManifest.xml of the app **Keyguard** of *Lollipop* located at: [$(AOSP_Root_Dir)/frameworks/base/packages/Keyguard/](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/Keyguard/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.keyguard"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.systemui"
    coreApp="true">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:process="com.android.systemui"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

    </application>
</manifest>
```

What's weird is: There is **NO** any components such activity, service, etc. in AndroidManifest.xml!

How does it get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intended to take out when you edited this to a shortened form, but looking at the version you link to it certainly does include a service thus:

```
    <service android:name=".KeyguardService"
        android:exported="true" />
```

EDIT: In the version you now link to, that service was removed by the checkin:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/380ecb81db52a9d0197ca969951d07b91c20d2b9

which did the following:

- Let Keyguard be a library, so we can use it in SystemUI.
- Implement a new KeyguardService in SystemUI, and bind that service
  from PhoneWindowManager.

Comment: My first citation link is wrong (of 4.4).  Now it's correct (of 5.0).

Comment: If the AndroidManifest.xml has no components, then how to load it into SystemUI as a library?

Comment: This is explained in the commit comment mentioned in this question, in short, the component is moved.  The implementation code which remains is *linked* into it.